# Getting error: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1

Tags: python-2.7, m2crypto, pyopenssl

I Have installed python 2.7.2 and M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7.egg-info in my Windows XP SP3 machine and wherever i am using import statement:

`from M2Crypto import X509,ASN1,Rand,EVP,RSA` its throwing error

**DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.**

it seems like M2Crypto version is not supported with Python2.7 and windows XP SP3.
In addition to that I am using pyOpenSSL-0.13.winxp32-py2.7.msi for openSSL.

Can anybody help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Finally solved the issue, I was correct to suspecting M2Cryto's version "M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.7" which is not supporting in windows XP SP3 but when i installed M2Crypto-0.20.2.win32-py2.7 version, its working as expected.